# How to propagate Setting Class throughout entire project

Tags: c#, design-patterns, wpf

Here's my setup:

1. Entity Framework Backend
2. Large WPF project that has a main window with 3-4 user controls on it, each of which has 3-4 user controls on it (and so on, in some cases)

What I currently have:

```
public class MySettings
{
   public string Property1 { get; set; }
   public string Property2 { get; set; }
   public string Property3 { get; set; }
   public string Property4 { get; set; }
}

public class FileService
{
    public void HandleFile();
    public event EventHandler FileChanged;
}


public class UserControl1
{
    MySettings settings;
    FileService fileService;
}

public class UserControl2
{
    MySettings settings;
    FileService fileService;
}
```

There are quite a few UserControls (or VMs) that need to know about the settings class.  Here's an example of what happens:

1. Application loads. User goes in to the "Settings Window".
2. User changes settings.
3. UserControl1 gets notified of a settings change, and adds a new user control
4. UserControl2 gets notified of a settings change, and makes a stackpanel visible
5. etc, etc, etc.

My dilemma:

How do I handle all user controls and windows having access to these classes?  Specific questions:

1. Should I create a main settings class in a top-level ViewModel and propagate this settings class through to a series of sub viewmodels?
2. Should I create a static class to handle all of these?
3. Should the FileService also be propagated down through each ViewModel? Is there a cleaner way to do Services while ensuring each control/window is using the same one?

Comment: You should have a look at [Prism](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/wpf/Introduction.html), it's build to solve those problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is best depends on the project you like to have.

My case: I have a small app. There are some settings, no tests.
Solution: Static class methods to ask and set.
[Example](https://github.com/niccokunzmann/mundraub-android/blob/e2eea1f61033fe5dd0641ea544e4d70c8cfa749f/app/src/main/java/eu/quelltext/mundraub/common/Settings.java#L578)

```
public static boolean IShouldAskTheUserToOpenThePrivacyPolicy() {
        return !userHasReadThePrivacyPolicy;
}
```

used later like

```
if (Settings.IShouldAskTheUserToOpenThePrivacyPolicy()) askIfTheUserLikesToSeeThePrivacyPolicy()
```

I thought about

- A static class as I have
- A Singleton: I would always write Settings.instance()
- Using different Settings objects/interfaces for different classes: These were good if I had tests.

Since Java would like me to introduce an Interface for each class' own settings, I rather go for the anti pattern of a fat class here, making the place for future contribution by other people obvious. If it were Python, I would still use the class and have tests.

How I propagate the changes:
You can observe the settings. Objects can attach as an Observer (Pattern).

With the file service it is again your choice. I do not know what you want to do and what you face.

Language:
If I rename Settings to UserPreferences, there it is clear, that there is only one user in the app. In a server application however, this must not be singleton/static class.
With "FileService" it is of equal thought. "FileService" does not reveal anything about what it does or what needs it responds to in deed. So, I cannot tell you. If you answer to what it is the FileService does for whom? Then, probably you will not need to ask me.